# Generating all possible Tic Tac Toe boards with symmetry

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I am writing a genetic algorithm program that will develop the best possible solution to solving a board of Tic Tac Toe. I have done a lot of research and have found the there are 765 possible board combinations, when the symmetry of the board is taken into account. I need to write a code that will generate every combination, but I cannot figure out how to do this. I am new to coding, and cannot figure out how to incorporate the symmetry into the code.

How would you go about creating a code that generates every possible unique board combination (symmetry taken into account) of a Tic Tac Toe board?

[Here](http://www.egr.msu.edu/~kdeb/papers/k2007002.pdf)'s a good document explaining symmetries:

Thank you

Comment: What have you already researched?

Comment: http://www.egr.msu.edu/~kdeb/papers/k2007002.pdf this was a very useful document I found

Comment: This game is play by 2 persons or one person plays with a computer. The computer input depends on the user markers and vice versa. Think about how you would play and try to code that into your program. It does come under artificial intellegent. You can make the computer learn the wrong answer and only input in the correct moves. Btw, tic-tac-toe, if play properly it will always result to a draw, no one wins.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for taking into account board symmetry? Is it actually required by the algorithm (probably not)? Do you need it to save space (probably not)? Please clarify how you intend to exploit symmetry, as it affects the approaches you can use. Otherwise, this is premature optimization and needless complication.

Comment: without symmetry there are 19,683 possible combinations, which would take a very, very long time for the computer to run, especially when it is running the code thousands of times (to evolve the algorithm).

Comment: It would be beneficial if you could explain (as an edit into your question) where these numbers are coming from and how symmetries are obtained. If you've already done some research then we don't need to start from scratch.

Comment: @LaurenK.: you could enumerate all possible boards, detect symmetry, eliminate the symmetry-ones and then test/run your genetic algorithm on the remaining saving a lot of both computational and develop-effort.

Comment: Is using a genetic algorithm part of the assignment or can another algorithm be used? I think that minimax is the standard way to implement AI for tic tac toe.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how would you go about detecting symmetry? That's where I'm stumped.

Comment: @LaurenK.: well you flip/rotate/... the board (implement these) and check whether there already exists such a board. If after one of such operations, the test succeeds, you eliminate the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like by building a game tree, like in [minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax), but instead of calculating the value of the boards, put them in your preferred data structure for storing all 765 boards. Some example code, if this helps:

```
//Where you'll save the unique boards
HashSet<Board> mySavedBoards = new HashSet<Board>();
mySavedBoards.add(emptyBoard) //add the original empty board

//player = 'X' or 'O'
public static void find_all_boards(Board board, String player) {
    for (Move move : board.get_all_possible_moves()) {
        board = board.applyMove(move, player);
        my_saved_boards.add(board);
        if(!board.isWin()) {
            next_player = (player == 'O') ? 'X' : 'O';
            find_all_boards(board, next_player);
        }
    }
}
```

- `get_all_possible_moves(board)` would just return a list of the empty squares in the grid (anywhere the player is allowed to go)
- `board.applyMove(move)` takes a move and returns the board that results from playing that move with player ('X' or 'O')
- `isWin()` returns whether this board is a victory for some player (i.e. don't continue looking for more boards)

This code will visit all the possible tic-tac-toe boards, but will have some repeats, so you'd have to manage this implicitly (override equals and hashCode for your Board class to do this check for you so that when you add the board to a HashSet it doesn't add duplicates

A lot of this will depend on your representations for the Board, making a move, and the players, but I hope this general idea helps!

EDIT: I see now see you were asking about how to generate the symmetric boards
I would use two methods you can write on a board: `flip()`, `rotate()`. You can use this method to  generate the 8 variants of a board, as is suggested in an answer below. You can than write your equals method to check if a given board is in the set of variants on another board

```
boolean equals(Board other) {
    //Insert normal checks for object type here
    HashSet<Board> variantsOfOther = other.variants();
    return variantsOfOther.contains(this)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A board B has 1 to 8 symmetric variants including itself. Three can be obtained by rotating B in 90-degree increments. The others can be found by mirroring the original and then rotating three more times. (Not all the rotation/reflections need be unique: The board with an X in the middle and all other squares the same value has no other variants.)

You can also easily assign a value in the range 0..(3^9)-1 to every board by thinking of it as a ternary number. E.g. if you assign 0 = blank, 1 = `O`, 2 =`X` and you have a board

```
X O _
_ X O
_ _ _
```

You can interpret this as `210021000`(base 3) = `15498`(base 10).

Let `variants(B)` be a function that accepts board B and returns a set of up to 8 symmetric variants.  Let `value(B)` return the integer value of board B as described above.

Now you can use a simple brute for algorithm:

```
U = {}
for B in the set of 19683 possible boards
  // Set y to the minimum-valued variant of B.
  y = argmin_{ x in variants(B) } . value(x)
  U = U + y // add y to the unique variants.
```

When you're done, U contains the unique boards

Comment: thank you so much! this is so helpful! I'm still wondering about how you would be able to find the symmetry in the different numbers? I've generated all 19683 possibilities, but am having trouble with the next part

Answer (score 1):

Not at all that troublesome. And there are 126 combinations, not 700 or thousands.

1. **Generate all integers between 0 and 511**, both inclusive
2. Grab the **2-base representation of each**, ie. the binary representation. Fill with zeroes before, so each binary representation always has 9 numbers, either 0 or 1. Eg. from your generated number 6 you get it's binary representation 1,1,0 and when you fill extra zeroes, you have 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0.

(You can do all this in loops, one by one, i just happen to use a parallel language called Dyalog APL, so i show them all together)

Here. Binary:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 <- this is 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 <- this is 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 <- 6
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 <- 9
...
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 <- 77
...
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 <- 511
```

You (the computer) are one, the opponent is zero.

3. **Count the number of ones in each**. If the opponent started the game, **take only rows with 4 ones**. If the computer started the game, **take only rows with 5 ones**. In both cases, you end up with 126 rows.

Here are the 15 first rows (of 126) to retain, when the opponent started the game (would occupy too much space to write 126 rows here):

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

And here are *all* rows to retain (opponent started), re-shaped into 3 by 3 tables - same data but presented slightly differently:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 1│1 1 1│1 1 1│1 1 1│1 1 1│1 1 1│
│0 0 1│0 1 0│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│1 0 0│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 1│1 1 1│1 1 1│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 1│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 1│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 1│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 1│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 1│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 1│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│
│1 1 1│1 1 1│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│1 1 1│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│1 1 1│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 0│1 1 1│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│1 1 1│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

See where this is going? :-) These are your "all combinations".

4. At any point during the game, **filter the rows above** with the **current game status**. Example: The opponent started by placing his O in the upper left corner, and the computer replied by placing it's X in the center, to which the opponent replied by placing his O at center in upper row.

Hence the game now looks like this:

```
┌─┬─┬─┐
│0│0│ │
├─┼─┼─┤
│ │1│ │
├─┼─┼─┤
│ │ │ │
└─┴─┴─┘
```

or the same, flattened:

```
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│0│0│ │ │1│ │ │ │ │ │
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

Keep only rows matching this (ie. columns 1 and 2 are 0, column 5 is 1). Now you have only these rows = these possible outcomes of the game:

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

5. Re-shape each row into 3 by 3.

Same, easier to see:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│
│0 1 0│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 1│1 1 1│1 1 1│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 1│0 1 1│0 1 1│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 0│1 1 1│
│1 1 1│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 1│0 1 0│1 0 0│0 0 0│
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

These are all possible outcomes of the game, **from this stage onwards**. Obviously you'd now count the number of ones in each row, each column, diagonally and diagonally. Extract those alternatives that have 3 ones in a row, and from those, elect one, place your next X. Don't know which one, or how you optimise that - i guess you need to do some mambo jambo :-). Should be simple enough though. This is only rough guidance.

When thinking closer, **you need to maintain two data sets**, because you also want to process from the opponents point of view, to **hinder him from getting 3 in a line**. Ie. have a similar data set where the opponent is 1, you 0, count rows, columns, diagonals, and **react if any of those sums to 3 - then you must stop him!** Same principle, just manage a bit differently, as needed.

(NOTE: In parallel to all this, you must keep track of free slots! Should be simple, a 9-lenght array where 1 indicates occupied, for example. Just update it as the game advances. It's purpose is to a) define where the compu can checkmark, and b) verify that the opponent uses a free slot)

6. You (computer) place your X somewhere, opponent reacts, you obviously go back to step 4, and do the filtering again (stop him from getting 3 in a line + optimise your own move). Etc.